# ng-cli: hidden .git directory is created ? Breaking the link?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have just started to use the NG cli, everything is working but I notice that it has created a hidden directory .git which is where git is managed. Problem is that I have placed the generated directory by ng-cli into an existing repository and now my IDE is complaining that the directory where ng-cli created its files is an UNREGISTERED ROOT.

So the quick fix here would be to just remove the `.git` directory, I have already a .git create further down and my application level ROOT>

Is this safe to do?

Why does the ng-cli create the git-managed directory ?

Any ideas ? I am confused if it is safe to delete it or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this safe to do?

Yes, `ng-cli` just initializes a new git repository after it creates sample files installs all dependencies. It creates only one commit from the sample files. But the repository itself is not linked to any remote repository. So you can safely delete it if you already have other `git` repository.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I have now removed it.

Comment: I did this, but it the angular project folder still registers as a submodule...